# Background service after closing activity in Android

Tags: android, service, background-process

I try to create application, that check some remote database for news and activities. When app is running, it's work ok, app checks, shows notification, etc. But if user close app, everything stops. Is it possible to create background service in the application, that works after application closed (for send local notification, for example)? And if it's possible, what I have to do?

P.S. I know about Firebase and Google Cloud, but I want to create independent app.

Comment: are you saying you could not find any information about this at all? not in the 100 questions already posted about this?

Comment: Exactly. Nothing relevant for me. Most of info I found, was about Firebase. That's why I wrote P.S.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
As @Flo We said Service is the only option you can use

public class BackGroundService extends Service{
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e("Service","Started");

//Write your code here to run in background


        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

}
```

start service using Intent, don't stop the service on onDestroy and it will continue running in background

Answer (score 0):

[Services](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html) are pretty much your only option. But you never know when your Service is killed, and it keeps getting stricter as Android evolves.

Comment: So there are no options to make client-side  remote database  "scaner"?

Comment: i mean, that would be the way to go. Start a service and poll against your remote database. You need to be aware though, that the Android System or the user can stop background processes at any time.

Comment: You can even trigger Services on System Boot. I'm just not sure if that's still possible with Marshmallow +